# Watching variables from iframe in IE9 Developer tools

Tags: internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

In Internet Explorer 9, a page containing javascript is running within an iframe.

I want to add a watch to a variable in the iframe's global (window) context.
In the Developer Tools, under the Script-tab, when I add the variable name to the Watch, I just get the value:

> "\'myvar\' is undefined"

How do I watch variables in an iframe in IE9 Developer Tools?